# Unsure why Scrapy response.xpath is passing a list

Tags: python, xpath, byte, scrapy

This spider is meant to take a list of urls within a domain and write the XPath contents to an html file. I can get it to work when opening a txt file as 'a+' and writing a string but if I want to open an html file as 'ab+' neither a string nor the response.xpath result will work. The latter gives me this error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

I can't work out where the list comes from though.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'FirstSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    with open("urls.txt", "rt") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'blah-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'ab+') as f:
            f.write(response.xpath("//*[@id='content']").extract())
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @lukasz-salitra

Comment: What is unclear about the message? `response.xpath().extract()` is a `list`. If you want just one, try `.extract_first()` but it's still very likely going to be an object, and not `bytes`. All in all, you're solving the wrong problem: don't do file I/O from within a Spider, it is a race condition waiting to happen **and** makes your code hard to test

Answer (score 0):

Replace `extract()` with `get()` (or `extract_first()`).